# Strange debugger problem?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have created this datastructure:

```
class Event
{
public:
    Event(EVENT_TYPE type, void* pSender = 0, int content1 = 0,  
        int content2 = 0, int content3 = 0, int content4 = 0);
    ~Event(void);

// ... some functions

protected:
    EVENT_TYPE itsType;
    void* itsPointerToSender;
    int itsContent_1;
    int itsContent_2;
    int itsContent_3;
    int itsContent_4;
    int numStacked;
};
```

whose constructor is simply

```
Event::Event(EVENT_TYPE type, void* pSender, int content1, int content2, int content3, int content4)
    :   itsType(type),
    itsPointerToSender(pSender),
    itsContent_1(content1),
    itsContent_2(content2),
    itsContent_3(content3),
    itsContent_4(content4),
    numStacked(0)
{
}
```

For some strange reason I can't understand, the VS debugger cannot and will not show me whatever is contained in `itsContent_4`. If I put a watch on the variable, `itsContent_4` gives me a `symbol "itsContent_4" not found` while doing the same thing with `itsContent_3` works perfectly. I'm not sure the variable even exists as far as the compiler is concerned!

Am I missing something here?

**Edit:** Now it seems (even stranger) that changing the order of the variables in the declaration creates an even bigger mess! I tried placing `itsContent_4` before `itsContent_1` and now `itsContent_1` is being initialized with the value intended for `itsContent_4`! What is going on here? I'm suspecting something to do with naming, so I'll try renaming them all and see what happens.

**Edit 2:** Yes, apparently changing the variable names to `itsContent_a` instead of `itsContent_1` and so forth works perfectly. Is there some restriction as to using numbers in a variable name?

Comment: Perhaps it is getting optimized out. Try either making it volatile or making sure that the assignment has some side effect (the variable is used later in code).

Comment: Definitely being used later on. And I'm trying this without optimization anyway.

Comment: There is no C++ restriction on using digits in a variable name (except that they may not start the name); everything you've written looks like perfectly good C++ to me.  You could do a listing with preprocessor expansion and check out those names, in case something odd is happening with macros.  Other than that, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like the debugger is using the wrong .pdb file.  Tools + Options, Debugging, General, ensure that "Require source files to exactly match the original version" is checked.

While debugging with a breakpoint active, use Debug + Windows + Modules and right-click your executable in the list.  Click "Symbol Load Information" to find out where the debugger found the .pdb file.

Another possible mishap is that this class is defined in a separately compiled executable, like a DLL, which was compiled with incompatible settings.  So that the layout of the object no longer matches.  That's not that likely in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you're not trying to debug a release build. In a release build the optimiser can remove unused variabled and change the order in which statements are executed. This can be confusing when debugging.

Comment: I'm on debug mode, but thanks anyway. The problem seems to occur because of the numeric suffixes of the itsContent variables...

Comment: Could some kind of macro substitution be occuring? Do you have the string "content" #defined?

Comment: Whenever I use #define I make use of capital letters, so that shouldn't be a problem, and anyway neither "content" nor "CONTENT" is defined. Dunno, never came across something like this before.

Comment: I wonder if the code you're seeing is the same as what is being fed to the compiler. Try generating a preprocessed file (right click source file in workspace and choose properties, choose Preprocessor, and select Generate Preprocessed File, and choose "Without Line Numbers". When you rebuild you'll get a <filename>.i file. Locate your class definition and constructor in it and check that the proprocessor isn't modifying them.

Comment: I've tried that now and it shows the exact same code. Having said that, I tried going back from using letter suffixes to numerical ones and now it's working well once again. I really have no idea what caused the problem. Maybe the class was not being compiled properly somehow (in fact, I had been using an Event class with only 3 itsContent variables, and the compiler was kind of using that same old class even after recompiling...)